# Is the set $\{\lambda \in C ~|~\exists \{x_n\} \subset H, \|x_n\| = 1 \ni (Tx_n, Ax_n) \rightarrow \lambda~ and~ \|Tx_n\| \rightarrow \|T\|\}$ convex?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, functions

Let $T,A$ be bounded linear operators on an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space $ H $.

Let us consider the following set $$W_0(A)=\{\lambda \in C ~|~\exists \{x_n\} \subset H, \|x_n\| = 1 \ni (Tx_n, Ax_n) \rightarrow \lambda~ \mathrm{and}~ \|Tx_n\| \rightarrow \|T\|\}.$$

The set $W_0(A)$ is non-empty, closed, and convex. I am clear about non-empty and closed. But I am not clear about the set is convex or not. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what does this $\ni$ symbol mean there?

Comment: Can you please edit the notation in your question?  The set $ W_0(A) $ should specify (a) a base set $ \{ \lambda \in ? | ... \} $, and the $ \ni $ is confusing and used incorrectly.

Comment: @JustDroppedIn Some people use it to mean “such that”

Comment: @gen-zreadytoperish Lol, I didn't know that, thanks

Comment: @JakeMirra I highly doubt the OP wrote that on his own. It’s probably something that appeared in a textbook that he is now asking about here. Why should he edit that if that’s how it appeared?

Comment: $\{\lambda \in C\}$, thanks, $\ni$ means such that here.

Comment: May I ask how you were able to prove that $W_0(A)$ is not bounded? also, wouldn't $W_0(A,T)$ be a more appropriate notation?